# Присвоить свой ключ значению при array_push

Tags: php

Как можно присвоить свой ключ значению для массива? Сейчас файлам по умолчанию присваивается ключ **"0"** и т.д. Как бы мне сделать так, чтобы ключ назначался со слова img, а потом уже img1, img2..... Вот такой способ не подойдет array_push($arrImg, ('img' => $filename)). Мне не нужен массив внутри json

```html
$arrImg = [];
foreach ($file as $key => $item) {
....тут всякий код, который на выходе отдает имя файла в $filename
затем я записываю имя файла в массив $arrImg

array_push($arrImg, $filename);
}

Сливаю массив с содержанием и названием файла вместе
$form = array_merge($form, $arrImg);
$content = json_encode($form);

На выходе получаю 
{"title":"1","text":"1","active":"1","ver":"v1","0":"20220222162619759.jpg"}
```

Comment: `$arr['img1'] = $filename;`

Comment: @ArchDemon может быть добавлено не известное кол-во файлов. Пробую так: $arr['img'.$i++] = $filename; array_push($arrImg, $arr); Но на выходе {"0":{"img0":"20220222164148578.jpg"}, а нужно "img0":"20220222164148578.jpg"

Comment: $arr['img' . $key] = $filename; вместо array_push

Comment: @DanielProtopopov добавляет правильно, но теперь, когда загружаю несколько файлов, в массиве только один(

Comment: Потому что `$key` не увеличивается очевидно.

Comment: @u_mulder дело не в key, а в том, что в foreach array_push поочередно добавляет имена файлов в массив, а это нет -  $arr['img' . $key] = $filename;

Comment: https://3v4l.org/6t10g Вот как это работает. Почему это не работает у тебя - подскажут только телепаты.